Formatted the USB Drive, but I can't access it now. | Read-Only
Formatted the USB Drive, but I can't access it now.
Tried to again Format the "USB Drive" from Disks Utility and GParted however, failed.
Getting the following warning in GParted:
Unable to open /dev/sdd read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdd has been opened read-only.
Unable to open /dev/sdd read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdd has been opened read-only.
/dev/sdd: unrecognised disk label



does this Linux Questions post help?

Try the following:
Open a terminal.
Run in it:
 sudo gparted

From gparted, select your USB, verify that it is really your USB and not another drive.
Unmount it if it is mounted.
Create a new partition table.
Create a partition with ext4 file system for Linux only or exfat for Linux and Microsoft.
Apply the changes
Close gparted.
Close the terminal.
Remove the USB and insert it again.
If the USB is still in read-only mode it may have expired.
